# Getting NoClassdef on HMAC_SHA1 in Webpshere

Tags: java, security, websphere

We have WAS 6.0 (I know) .2.43 ND running in multiple regions.

Our Dev-B region runs fine, but Dev-C throws a java exception when we make web-calls (at least this is what the developer tells me)...Same code in both regions and I checked the obvious suspects (Global security, SSL ciphers etc) and they all seem to match. Here's the stack trace from SystemErr:

```
[8/1/12 4:02:31:758 EDT] 0000005c ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Could not invoke the service() method on servlet action. Exception thrown : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(DashoA12275)
    at net.oauth.signature.HMAC_SHA1.computeSignature(HMAC_SHA1.java:73)
    at net.oauth.signature.HMAC_SHA1.getSignature(HMAC_SHA1.java:39)
    at net.oauth.signature.OAuthSignatureMethod.getSignature(OAuthSignatureMethod.java:83)
    at net.oauth.signature.OAuthSignatureMethod.sign(OAuthSignatureMethod.java:54)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.utils.LTIUtil.generateSignature(LTIUtil.java:62)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.web.struts.lti.action.BaseLTIAction.generateSignature(BaseLTIAction.java:238)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.web.struts.lti.action.BaseLTIAction.execute(BaseLTIAction.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:106)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1796)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:887)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:566)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:952)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1039)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)

    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(DashoA12275)
    at net.oauth.signature.HMAC_SHA1.computeSignature(HMAC_SHA1.java:73)
    at net.oauth.signature.HMAC_SHA1.getSignature(HMAC_SHA1.java:39)
    at net.oauth.signature.OAuthSignatureMethod.getSignature(OAuthSignatureMethod.java:83)
    at net.oauth.signature.OAuthSignatureMethod.sign(OAuthSignatureMethod.java:54)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.utils.LTIUtil.generateSignature(LTIUtil.java:62)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.web.struts.lti.action.BaseLTIAction.generateSignature(BaseLTIAction.java:238)
    at com.harcourt.hsp.web.struts.lti.action.BaseLTIAction.execute(BaseLTIAction.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:106)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1796)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:887)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminaters(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:566)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:952)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1039)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
```

Thanks for your help. I'm sure it's a config that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance` is not able to be resolved.  If you want to try some low-hanging fruit before full blown troubleshooting: Are you missing a jar?  Does the class need to be added to your classpath?

Ultimately, the best way to resolve the issue is a logical step by step analysis.  This [3 part article](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html) will walk you through troubleshooting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. It's a relatively short read that I suspect will probably answer your question.

For completeness, I've included the short version *(pulled from the articles mentioned above)*:

1. Review the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error and identify the
   missing Java class. *(In this case javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance)*
2. Verify and locate the missing Java class from your compile / build
   environment
3. Determine if the missing Java class is from your application code,
   third part API or even the Java EE container itself. Verify where
   the missing JAR file(s) is / are expected to be found
4. Once found, verify your runtime environment Java classpath for any
   typo or missing JAR file(s)
5. If the problem is triggered from a Java EE application, perform the
   same above steps but verify the packaging of your EAR / WAR file for
   missing JAR and other library file dependencies such as MANIFEST
6. Perform a code walkthrough of the affected class and determine if it
   contains static initializer code (variables & static block)
7. Review your server and application logs and determine if any error
   originates from the static initializer code
8. Once confirmed, analyze the code further and determine the root
   cause of the initializer code failure. You may need to add some
   extra logging along with proper error handling to prevent and better
   handle future failures of your static initializer code going forward